# Un formato de fechas que entre en los datos DATE de phpmyadmin

Tags: java, phpmyadmin

Tengo una tabla Seguro con la siguiente lista de variables:

```
int idSeguro;
String nif;
String nombre;
String ape1;
String ape2;
int edad;
int numHijos;
LocalDate fechaCreacion;
```

Y lo quiero relacionar con esta tabla que tengo en phpMyAdmin.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este esto es lo que me veo al intentar introducir una fila en la tabla.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como consigo introducir correctamente la fecha?

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he arreglado. Me habia olvidado que al introducir un valor en la tabla en la variable DATE debia ponerlo con sus comillas, al igual que los String.

```
int d=s.executeUpdate("insert into seguro values("+seguro.idSeguro+",'"+seguro.nif+"','"             +seguro.nombre+"','"+seguro.ape1+"','"+seguro.ape2+"','"+seguro.edad+"',"
                +seguro.numHijos+",'"+seguro.fechaCreacion+"')");
```